# How can i fix the setInterval part, is that even it?

Tags: html

I'm working on a game named Factory Tycoon and have spotted a bug which I can't resolve myself. Every second you get plus what your items per second is on your items but it is failing to do so. Feel free to test the code. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Factory Tycoon</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var money = 1000;
        var items = 0;
        var itemsps = 1;
        var dropper1Cost = 100;
        var dropper1Audio = new Audio('Audio/dropper1Sound.mp3');

        function addDropper() {
            if (money <= dropper1Cost - 1) {
                alert('Not Enough Money.')
            }
            if (money >= dropper1Cost) {
                dropper1Audio.play()
                itemsps += 1;
                money -= dropper1Cost;
                dropper1Cost += 100;
            }
        }

        setInterval(function renderMoney() {
            document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = "Money:" + money;
        })

        setInterval(function renderItemsProcessedPS() {
            document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = "Items Processed:" + items;
        })

        setInterval(function renderItemsProcessedPS() {
            document.getElementById('itemsps').innerHTML = "Items Processed Per         Second:" + itemsps;
        }, 1000)
    </script>
</head>

<h4 id="money"></h4>
<h4 id="items"></h4>
<h4 id="itemsps"></h4>

<body>
    <img src="Images/dropper1IMG.png" onclick="addDropper()">

</html>
```

There isn't much code as I've only just started to develop it tonight :).

Comment: well your setIntervals have no time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few issues in the code:

- `<h4>` elements need to be inside the `<body>` element
- the `</body>` end tag is missing
- the `setInterval` is called before all elements had a chance to load, which will make it error, so I wrapped them in an `init` function and called that on body load

*Side note, this code can be optimized with `addEventListener` for the load event etc., but here you have a start*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Factory Tycoon</title>
  <style>
    span { display: inline-block; padding: 5px; background: #ddd; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var money = 1000;
    var items = 0;
    var itemsps = 1;
    var dropper1Cost = 100;
    var dropper1Audio = new Audio('Audio/dropper1Sound.mp3');

    function addDropper() {
      if (money <= dropper1Cost - 1) {
        alert('Not Enough Money.')
      }
      if (money >= dropper1Cost) {
        dropper1Audio.play()
        itemsps += 1;
        money -= dropper1Cost;
        dropper1Cost += 100;
      }
    }

    function init() {
      setInterval(function renderMoney() {
        document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = "Money:" + money;
      })

      setInterval(function renderItemsProcessedPS() {
        document.getElementById('items').innerHTML = "Items Processed:" + items;
      })

      setInterval(function renderItemsProcessedPS() {
        document.getElementById('itemsps').innerHTML = "Items Processed Per         Second:" + itemsps;
      }, 1000)
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">

  <h4 id="money"></h4>
  <h4 id="items"></h4>
  <h4 id="itemsps"></h4>

  <span onclick="addDropper()">Click Me</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but code still doesn't work as i ran it and the setInterval function doesn't work. Also about the <h4> tags, i've done them in the head in all of my other games and they were successful.

Comment: @TobyBridle 1: The above code works. If it does not in your code, you most likely missed something what the above does. ... 2: It is invalid to put elements such `<h4>` before the `<body>` tag. Some browser will still try render them correct but some won't, so the outcome will be unpredictable. ... Still, it is up to you if you want to code proper html or not, and if your are going to publish this public, you will get in a lot of trouble not following the way it is supposed to be

Comment: What browser do you use, i often use chrome when using HTML, even when i run the code snippet it doesn't work. All of the images and sounds work but not the increasePerSecond of Items. Many Thanks,

Comment: @TobyBridle I tested on Chrome and Edge ... both works

Comment: oh thx, would it make any difference what OS we're on - I'm on Win7 SP1 and have 4GB Ram and 256MB Graphics 3GHz. I'm guessing that you're on Win10.... :D

Comment: @TobyBridle Yes, Win 10 ... so I can't say why it does not work on yours, but I can say the above code works

Comment: Btw you're site is beautiful i wish you the best of luck with that - you must be a pro seeing as you've been working with stuff like this for that long! And when i wrote 3GHz thats my processor, and its quad-core.

Comment: It wouldn't be anything to do with the Chrome version would it?                                I'll download Edge and see if that makes a difference - thanks for your support!!

Comment: @TobyBridle Thanks .. and I use Chrome ver. 54, but no. You could take out the audio part to make sure that part is not cause any issue

Comment: no it still does not work, I deleted the new Audio variable and also removed it from the function. It still doesn't work. Unfortunately.